# How to store files on disk and guarantee that they get deleted in Java

Tags: java, file, unix

I need to store files that a user uploads.  I was instructed that I am to store it on the disk (and not try anything fancy like using database blobs or a cache system).

But from there, I need to figure out how to make sure that the files are eventually deleted (maybe an hour after they are last accessed).  This is on a Linux server.  So what is the best way to guarantee that the files are deleted?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this:

- You can run a cron job with `find $path -daystart -mtime +1 -exec rm "{}" \;` - that deletes all files created on day ago.
- Whenever a file is uploaded, you can list the folder in Java and delete all files which are too old
- You can add [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to your app to combine the two options.

Since you're on Linux, file locking won't be an issue. You can always delete files on Linux, even when a process is still using them (Linux will keep the file around as long as the process uses it and delete it afterwards).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be some process which periodically examined the uploads directory and deleted every file that was more than an hour old.

If you do it this way you don't need to worry about things like keeping track of files across server restarts.

Could be something like this:

```
File uploads =  new File("/tmp/uploads");

FileFilter hourOld = new FileFilter() {
  @Override
  public boolean accept(File file) {
    return file.lastModified() < System.currentTimeMillis() - 60 * 60 * 1000;
  }
};

for (File file : uploads.listFiles(hourOld)) {
  file.delete();
}
```

You could schedule this using the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Answer (score 1):

To guarantee deletion, I would run a separate process which starts as a service on start-up to remove files. This way they will be deleted even if your program is not running.

Usually, all you need to to ensure files are deleted when a service is running.  You just have to ensure the file is closed, and you have a background thread which checks the last accessed time periodically.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using cron4j, you can find examples here http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/manual.php?PHPSESSID=oakn2j011nkoeoqv791pfcs4q3

Answer (score 1):

The [tmpwatch](http://oreilly.com/linux/command-directory/cmd.csp?path=t/tmpwatch) program is designed to perform this exact task.  Note that it won't be able to work correctly if you have the filesystem mounted with the noatime option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use temp files. You can define if they should get deleted on VM termination :

```
public static File createTempFile(String name, String suffix) {
    try {
        File temp = File.createTempFile(name, "." + suffix);

        temp.deleteOnExit();
        return temp;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However there is no strong gurantee, as the deletion will only succeed during a regular termination.